# How to display data of multiple objects in angular component or how to add them to one array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, leaflet, turfjs

In parent component inside `forEach` loop I'm getting coordinates of each layer on map and than getting ones that are crossing with the point of click. Using `EventEmitter` I'm sending this data to child component.

```
this.airspaceLayers.forEach((o: any) => {

    let coord = o.geometry.coordinates[0];
    let poly = turf.polygon([coord]);

    this.map.on('click', <LeafletMouseEvent> (e) => {

        let lat = e.latlng.lat;
        let lng = e.latlng.lng;
        let pt = turf.point([lng,lat])
        let isInside = turf.inside(pt, poly);

        if (isInside) {
                layerObjData.push(o);
                this.intersectedLayers.emit({layerObjData});
        }
```

**In child component I'm reciving data by this way:**

```
if (this.intersectedLayers && this.selectedRowIndex) {
    this.intersectedLayers.subscribe(data => {
        //console.log('check-how-many-iterations');
        //console.log("data",data);
        let arr: any[]  = [];

        Object.keys(data).forEach(function(item) {
            arr.push(data[item]);
        });

        this.intersectedLayersData = arr;
        //console.log("intersectedLayersData",this.intersectedLayersData);
```

...and finally I'm returning multiple objects from parent component like this:

```
intersectedLayersData [Array(1)]
    0: Array(1)
        0: {type: "TRA", designator: "EPTR94", availabilities: Array(1), info: Array(2), geometry: {…}}

intersectedLayersData [Array(1)]
    0: Array(1)
        0: {type: "TRA", designator: "EPTR129A", availabilities: Array(1), info: Array(2), geometry: {…}}
```

I need to display data all of the data in the angular component html as separate divs and I wonder how to do it proper.
I was hoping that arr.push() inside foreach will add each object to one array, but instead I've got two separate objects. 
It would be nice to display it something like :

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of intersectedLayers">
    <h3>{{obj.intersectedLayers.designator}}</h3>
    (etc...)
</div>
```

I was reading that is possible to display this data using keyvalue and `Pipes`, but it did't work for me that way, it was cases with one `object`, not multiple.

**How to display this data in a easy and a optimal manner?**

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?:

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of intersectedLayersData[0]">
    <h3>{{obj.designator}}</h3>
    (etc...)
</div>
```

Comment: It does but only for the first object, but trying to acces to intersectedLayersData[1] wont display any data . Same as direct intersectedLayersData.designator. Question is how to display it for all of the data object/array doesnt matter, one array would be probably more effective.

Answer (score 0):

According to Angular's official docs, you use `@input` properties to pass data from parent component to children (upper to lower), while you use events/event emitters vise-versa (lower to upper).
Anyway, what I'm saying that if you already used an event emitter, all you have to do is to move it to a higher service and consume it anywhere you'd like to.
then you will be able to push in a single object and subscribe to it from anywhere.

**P.S.** make sure you use a Singelton service for this purpose.
Hopefully, you find this explanation helpful.